# How do I get puts to work on my class?

Tags: ruby

```
class X
  def initialize
    @name = "Bob"
  end
  blah blah
end

puts X.new  # I want this to print X:Bob
puts [X.new, X.new] # I want this to print [X:Bob, X:Bob]
```

Comment: @sawa: Stack Overflow ate the full text.

Comment: @Andrew, @Zabba Thanks. I didn't check that. Now I see that Andrew fixed it.

Comment: accept answers for your previous posts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override the `to_s` method of your class:

```
class X
  def initialize
    @name = "Bob"
  end

  def to_s
    "X:#{@name}"
  end
end

puts X.new  # prints X:Bob
puts [X.new, X.new].to_s # prints [X:Bob, X:Bob]
```

Comment: @alexloh, note the method is named `initialize`, not `init`. Also, you could improve the code to use `"#{self.class.name}:#{@name}"` so that the class name is not hard-coded.

Comment: The code block was only meant as an example so I didn't spell out initialize. But I didn't know you could do that with the class name --- Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to have `initialize`, not `init`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer is incomplete. Just by changing the method name `init` to the correct name will not print `X:Bob` - the `to_s` method is needed here.

Comment: @Zabba: He asked more than one question in the one questions or less lane. The default `inspect` will mention that `@name` is "Bob".